# Django admin: __str__ returned non-string (type int)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a homework assignment to create an API in Django. I am getting the following error on two of my models when I click the link in the Django admin framework:

```
TypeError at /officer/
__str__ returned non-string (type int)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/officer/
Django Version:     3.0.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__str__ returned non-string (type int)

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py in display_value, line 221
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.7.5
Python Path: 

Error during template rendering

In template /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/horizontal/select.html, error at line 15
__str__ returned non-string (type int)
```

My other models appear to be working correctly. Here is some code from models.py:

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    subscriberID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscriptiontypecode = models.ForeignKey(SubscriptionType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    servicecode = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    requestdate = models.DateField()
    startdate = models.DateField()
    enddate = models.DateField()
    motifofcancellation = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    beneficiaryID = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subscriberID

class TransferredSubscription(models.Model):
    transferID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    transferfrom = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    transferto = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    requestdate = models.DateField()
    transferdate = models.DateField()
    subscriberID = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.transferID

class Officer(models.Model):
    officecode = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscriberID = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    startdate = models.DateField()
    enddate = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.officecode
```

TransferredSubscription works fine. I tried adding return str(self.officecode) and that still gives the same error.

Any insight why this may be happening?

EDIT: Adding the error traceback per request:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/officer/

Django Version: 3.0.4
Python Version: 3.7.5
Installed Applications:
['synerd',
 'backend',
 'rest_framework',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/horizontal/select.html, error at line 15
   __str__ returned non-string (type int)
   5 :     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label {% if style.hide_label %}sr-only{% endif %}">
   6 :       {{ field.label }}
   7 :     </label>
   8 :   {% endif %}
   9 : 
   10 :   <div class="col-sm-10">
   11 :     <select class="form-control" name="{{ field.name }}">
   12 :       {% if field.allow_null or field.allow_blank %}
   13 :         <option value="" {% if not field.value %}selected{% endif %}>--------</option>
   14 :       {% endif %}
   15 :        {% for select in field.iter_options %} 
   16 :           {% if select.start_option_group %}
   17 :             <optgroup label="{{ select.label }}">
   18 :           {% elif select.end_option_group %}
   19 :             </optgroup>
   20 :           {% else %}
   21 :             <option value="{{ select.value }}" {% if select.value|as_string == field.value|as_string %}selected{% endif %} {% if select.disabled %}disabled{% endif %}>{{ select.display_text }}</option>
   22 :           {% endif %}
   23 :       {% endfor %}
   24 :     </select>
   25 : 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 724, in render
    context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 696, in get_context
    'post_form': self.get_rendered_html_form(data, view, 'POST', request),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 511, in get_rendered_html_form
    return self.render_form_for_serializer(serializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 521, in render_form_for_serializer
    {'style': {'template_pack': 'rest_framework/horizontal'}}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 372, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 192, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 87, in render_field
    return renderer.render_field(field, style)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 351, in render_field
    return template.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 161, in render
    values = self.sequence.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 670, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 795, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 857, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 215, in iter_options
    self.get_choices(cutoff=self.html_cutoff),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 202, in get_choices
    for item in queryset
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 202, in <listcomp>
    for item in queryset
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 221, in display_value
    return str(instance)

Exception Type: TypeError at /officer/
Exception Value: __str__ returned non-string (type int)
```

EDIT 2: Adding some more code
views.py

```
class SubscriberView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Subscriber.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SubscriberSerializer

class TransferredSubscriptionView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TransferredSubscription.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransferredSubscriptionSerializer

class OfficerView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Officer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OfficerSerializer
```

urls.py

```
router.register('subscriber', views.SubscriberView)
router.register('transferredsubscription', views.TransferredSubscriptionView)
router.register('officer', views.OfficerView)
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Subscriber)
admin.site.register(TransferredSubscription)
admin.site.register(Officer)
```

serializers.py

```
class SubscriberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscriber
        fields = '__all__'

class TransferredSubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TransferredSubscription
        fields = '__all__'

class OfficerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Officer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: can you show the corresponding view?

Comment: Added some snippets from views.py, urls.py, admin.py, serializers.py

Comment: return str(self.transferId) and cast integers to strings.

Comment: Why define str methods like this on the objects at all?  Are you relying on that behavior somehow, and what happens with a new object that has "None" for the ID?

Comment: @AndrewBacker  I went through and commented out the def __str__(self): on the subscriber and office models, and still had the same problem...

then I went and did this to ALL of my models, and now everything is working - thanks!

Comment: @AndrewBacker to add... I had all of my models returning INT under the __str__ method, but with your advice I was able to modify each to return a string (i.e username instead of user ID #) and now everything is showing correctly in the API. Thanks again

Comment: Great, happy that worked!  In my opinion, str() should really only be called on a model either on purpose, or in debugging output.  It works well in the admin as a quick and dirty, but you probably want to have a custom function in your admin that gives better/clearer information.  As a basic, my _str_ is just `f"ModelName({self.name})"` or equally simple, but the default works as well.

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark one of the Answers below as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown us your `Office` model. Since `officecode` is an `Office` object, make sure you have defined the `__str__()` method in `Office` model. You could cast it to an `int` just in case.

```py
class Office(models.Model):
    officecode = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ....
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.officecode)
```

[The **str**() method is called whenever you call str() on an object.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#str)

Answer (score 1):

your `Subscriber.__str__` returns an int as well. change:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.subscriberID
```

to

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.subscriberID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your comments:

I can't tell exactly why the problem is happening from the stack trace alone, looking at the source code.  The other answer mentions calling `str` on the pk, but that didn't work.  To debug it you'd need to put a breakpoint where the exception happens and walk up the stack trace to see what the values are.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 221, in display_value
    return str(instance)
```

My best guess is that its getting back something that **looks** like a number, and raising an error.

1) Try removing all `__str__` implementations for models.  The aren't really needed since the base class does something good enough, unless you want to make it more attractive

2) Try returning more than a `str(int)` in there, so it can't be misinterpreted:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%s(%s)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.pk)
```

I can't find this specific error anywhere in django or drf, so without debugging it directly I'm out of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the database and creating it again, it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).